# Extracting repeated text in new column from phrases- compared to two columns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, multiple-columns

I have two columns ('Index 1' and 'Index 2') with keywords and I want to extract from 'Index 2' the duplicate words that are found in 'Index 1', in column 'Results'.

This is how the output should look:

| Indexed 1 | Indexed 2 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| comfort; ideal; manual | bra; comfort; manual | comfort; manual |
| shirt; basic; reservation | male; basic; female | basic |
| quality; stylish; basic; materials | stylish; female; shirt; materials | stylish; materials |

I've tried this code but it would only highlight the duplicate words from the same cell. I can't manage to adapt it to my needs, mostly because I'm new to VBA coding:

```
Sub HighlightDupesCaseInsensitive()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Delimiter As String
 
    Delimiter = InputBox("Enter the delimiter that separates values in a cell", "Delimiter", ", ")
 
    For Each cell In Application.Selection
        Call HighlightDupeWordsInCell(cell, Delimiter, False)
    Next
End Sub



Sub HighlightDupeWordsInCell(cell As Range, Optional Delimiter As String = " ", Optional CaseSensitive As Boolean = True)
    Dim text As String
    Dim words() As String
    Dim word As String
    Dim wordIndex, matchCount, positionInText As Integer
 
    If CaseSensitive Then
        words = Split(cell.Value, Delimiter)
    Else
        words = Split(LCase(cell.Value), Delimiter)
    End If
 
    For wordIndex = LBound(words) To UBound(words) - 1
        word = words(wordIndex)
        matchCount = 0
 
        For nextWordIndex = wordIndex + 1 To UBound(words)
            If word = words(nextWordIndex) Then
                matchCount = matchCount + 1
            End If
 
        Next nextWordIndex
 
        If matchCount > 0 Then
            text = ""
 
            For Index = LBound(words) To UBound(words)
                text = text & words(Index)
 
                If (words(Index) = word) Then
                    cell.Characters(Len(text) - Len(word) + 1, Len(word)).Font.Color = vbRed
                End If
 
                text = text & Delimiter
            Next
        End If
    Next wordIndex
End Sub
```

Can you please help?

Thank you!

Comment: People here will help you with *your* code, but typically questions with no posted code tend to get closed.

Comment: Also, this can be easily done through formulae depending on your version

Comment: Well, not doing it for you but this find the starting position of comfort in cell B2: FIND(LEFT(A2,FIND(";",A2,1)-1),B2,1) You can expand on it as needed.